# User following quota limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, has-many-through

I'm following Michael Hartl tutorial and want to set a method to limit the amount of users a person can follow

Should I set the limit in the model/relationship.rb

app/model/relationship.rb

```
validate :following_quota, :on => :create

private

def following_quota
 if user.active_relationships.size >= 3
  error.add(:base, 'exceeded follow limit')
 end
end
```

or should i set this is the model/user.rb

Comment: it is required to use a custom validator? What is active_relationships? A scope? A relation?

Comment: The controller is more or less for figuring out which views to render and for persistence. Code like this should be a custom validation in your model.

Comment: @MarsAtomic yes I've set the validation in the model

Comment: @lcguida its set in the model/user.rb

Comment: Please try to give your question a better title.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to reference associated data, you'll need to use `inverse_of`;

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :active_relationships, inverse_of: :user
end

#app/models/relationship.rb
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :active_relationships
end
```

The place you put the validation depends on which model you're calling.

I imagine you're creating a new `relationship`, which would mean you'd put it in the *relationship* model, using data from the `user` associative object:

```
#app/models/relationship.rb
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :active_relationships
   validate :max_followers, only: :create

   private

   def max_followers
      error.add(:base, 'exceeded follow limit') if user.active_relationships.size >= 3
   end
end
```

Comment: I don't think i need to create an inverse of the relationships if i have a destroy method in the relationships controller - Right now I'm validating the max_followers validation and I get this error in the log: NoMethodError (undefined method `active_relationships' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/relationship.rb:16:in `max_followers'
  app/models/user.rb:46:in `follow'
  app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:5:in `create'